# Неправильное присвоение массива в c++

Tags: c++, массивы

У меня есть следующий код:

```
struct figure_map {
bool rotation0[4][4];
bool rotation1[4][4];
bool rotation2[4][4];
bool rotation3[4][4];};

figure_map figure;`

figure.rotation1 = { {0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0}};
```

Компилятор ругается `E2188 Expression syntax`. Что не так?

Comment: C-style массивы нельзя присваивать. Используйте `std::array`, или инициализируйте сразу при объявлении `figure`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись с фигурными скобками вроде `int array[3] = {1,2,3}` работает только при *инициализации* массива.

То есть вот так делать можно:

```
int array[3] = {1,2,3};
```

А вот так нельзя:

```
int array[3];
array = {1,2,3};
```

---

У вас есть несколько вариантов.

Можно менять элементы по одному:

```
int array[3];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
```

Можно поместить массив в класс/структуру:

```
struct Array {int data[3];};

Array array;
array = {1,2,3};
```

Можно использовать `std::array`:

```
std::array<int,3> array;
array = {1,2,3};
```